# Not inserting into DataBase(MySQL) using ASP.NET (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to insert into DB, it gets updated only when i goto table properties,
and press "Execute SQL".

Here is the code:

```
  using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.Web.Configuration;
 using System.Configuration;
 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
String s;
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlConnection Con;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    s = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["my"].ConnectionString;

    Con=new SqlConnection(s);
    Con.Open();
    cmd=new SqlCommand("insert into stu values('"+TextBox1.Text+"','"+TextBox2.Text+"')",Con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    Con.Close();




  }
 }
```

What is wrong?It gets updated not Automatically,but when i goto the table contents,right click and press execute SQL.

**UPDATE:**
This will make things clear:

[image]

Only after this the row is affected.Any reasons?

**UPDATE2**

I know the the stmt. is working fine.But what can be the problem?Shoudn't it update automatically?Why i have to go to "Execute SQL"??

I'm using sql server

Comment: this is an asp page right? where do you want to see the update, i don't understand from your question. What do you mean by "It gets updated not Automatically"? Does the row get inserted into database or not?

Comment: its getting inserted, you can actually check by counting the number of rows in your table...

Comment: but the inserted new row isn't showing in your page right?

Comment: @BurhanUddin see update,yup right

Comment: whats your cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  returning??

Comment: @joeyrohan - is it solved?

Comment: @FathahRehmanP no!! i dont know what is the problem!

Comment: @i think its sql server .am i right?

Comment: @FathahRehmanP yup, right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question tag is given as 'mysql' but for me it looks as SQL server.

Your program is updating to database. But it will be visible only if you refresh the sql page.

Comment: Its not about refresh, i have to click on execute SQL!

Comment: @joeyrohan - My friend its updated. Please do one thing. Try to run your program. Then close that data edit window of your sql server management studio window. Then try to open it again you can see the newly inserted data.

Comment: havn't seen yet..i have ASP set up at college..Well see it day after :p

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about asp.net page....then u need to update the table content in page after insert...and `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` returns an integer,which represents no of row effected....you can check whether your query is working or not...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any problem

**Use the "Using" Statement in C#**

```
using (Con=new SqlConnection(s);)
{
    Con.Open();
    cmd=new SqlCommand("insert into stu values('"+TextBox1.Text+"','"+TextBox2.Text+"')",Con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    Con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the normal beahvior...
How can you say that data is not isnerted? Just because when you insert you open your SSMS and  check your table without out refereshing it...
You must know that while you open a table data in either "SELECT" form OR "EDIT" form in SSMS it disyplays all the rows currently inserted.
while you insert data form out side the SSMS, the data is inserted but can not be shown in your existing opend tableview, until you refresh it...

Note that by referesh i mean "Execute the SELECT or EDIT Query again"..

Comment: Even if i refresh it,it dosn't show any thing.Only when-> "Execute SQL"

Comment: Would you please explain how do you referesh?

Comment: Right click on table,refresh